# CoreTelephony returns nil when called inside unwanted Communication Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-telephony

Everywhere I can find the same solution to retrieve carrier information. So Im sure it works. but, For me its returning an error:

```
    2018-08-08 14:24:55.100318-0400 ReportSpam1Extension[4192:295308] 
    [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error
    Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
    com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo=
    {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
    com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.
```

The code that is generating this error is inside a message extension:

```
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider
print(carrier)
```

I have linked the binary as well. Im not sure what I am missing here

UPDATE: It works in the parent app but not in the extension! 
The extension I am using is (Unwanted Communication Extension)